# Facing problem with Jenkins and Sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

Hello this is my first question in stackoverflow i guess i dont know how to use it now. What i wanted to ask is i am facing problem while running sonar scanner through jenkins  and i have [provided the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRwOR.png).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your topic must be too short

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a missing space in the command line:

```
..../bin/sonar-scanner-Dsonar.project....
```

Should be:

```
..../bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.project....
```